# get this.defaultValue for a radio button

Tags: jquery, html

Im using this for a text input to detect a change from the default/loaded state of the object and then update the default value with the new one.

```
    $("input").on("change", function() {
        isDirty = (this.defaultValue !== this.value);
        if (isDirty)
            this.defaultValue = this.value;
    });
```

I want to fint out what a similar solutions would be for radio buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something that worked.
It probably more of a hack than a standard, but something that I would think JQuery can implement so you dont have to use improvised code like this, if they have not already.

Just forcefully remove the checked attribute from all the other radio buttons and then apply the default.

```
    $('input[type=radio][id=acuity1]').change(function() {
        $('input[id=acuity2]').removeAttr( "checked" );
        $('input[id=acuity3]').removeAttr( "checked" );

        isDirty = (this.defaultChecked !== $(this).is(':checked'));
        if (isDirty)
            this.defaultChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
    });
    $('input[type=radio][id=acuity2]').change(function() {
        $('input[id=acuity1]').removeAttr( "checked" );
        $('input[id=acuity3]').removeAttr( "checked" );

        isDirty = (this.defaultChecked !== $(this).is(':checked'));
        if (isDirty)
            this.defaultChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
    });
    $('input[type=radio][id=acuity3]').change(function() {
        $('input[id=acuity1]').removeAttr( "checked" );
        $('input[id=acuity2]').removeAttr( "checked" );

        isDirty = (this.defaultChecked !== $(this).is(':checked'));
        if (isDirty)
            this.defaultChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
    });
```

If there is a better way (and Im sure there might be) please share your thoughts.